# Pandas SUMIFS from table 2, for column in table 1

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sumifs

I have a big df with tarifs for aviation lines. you can specify data for concrete route, for example by airport of origination, airport of destination, aicraft, month.
Plain example of df:

```py
data = {'orig':['A','A','A','B','B','B'],
       'dest':['C','C','C','D','D','D'],
       'currency':['RUB','USD','RUB','USD','RUB','USD'],
        'tarif':[100,10,120,20,150,30]}
df=pd.DataFrame(data)
df
    orig    dest    currency    tarif
0   A         C       RUB        100
1   A         C       USD        10
2   A         C       RUB        120
3   B         D       USD        20
4   B         D       RUB        150
5   B         D       USD        30
```

I have df2, that contains aviation plan for concrete company. There you may find the same info, like month, orig,dest,aircraft
Plain example of df2:

```py
data2={'orig':['A','B'],
       'dest':['C','D']}
df2=pd.DataFrame(data2)
df2

   orig  dest
0    A    C
1    B    D
```

Task:for each row in df2, summurize tarif using conditions.

What I expect:

```py
  orig  dest RUB   USD
0   A    C   220    10
1   B    D   150    50
```

Thanks.

Comment: That sounds like a classical `gruopby/agg`. Ofc one can't try it on pictures. Would be nice if you gave plain text inputs and desired output.

Comment: Done, hope, that's  what u have meant

Comment: Kinda I have two questions though. In df1 there are two rows with flights from B to D with traifs in usd. You really want to added up? Not like a minimum or something? And what do you want to do with stuff for wich there is no line in df2? Just drop them? Maybe you should add that to your example so the behavior is clear.

Comment: Q1: For better understanding, Imagine you have line NYC-Berlin. During your trip, I will fly over different countries, these countries charge you for navigation service, each country has own tarif and currency. That is why, for one line B-D, you may have multiple rows with different usd tarifs. Ultimately, total cost u have, will be the sum.

Comment: Q2: In case there is no data, just 0. Depends on line, if u have flight within country borders, after filtering orig,dest, aircraft, month, u will get several rows in usd for example. Therefore eur, rur will be 0. In other case, u have international flight, and it implies flight over Germany and Russia. After filtering u will get rows with RUR, and EUR, so it wil be only usd = 0.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm

```
df = df.groupby(["orig", "dest", "currency"]).agg(sum).unstack()
df.columns = ['_'.join(col).strip() for col in df.columns.values]
df
```

gives me

```
           tarif_RUB  tarif_USD
orig dest                      
A    C           220         10
B    D           150         50
```

Which is your desired result but I haven't looked at df2 yet so I am afraid you have to describe better/extend your example so I have to do something with df2.

Comment: Oh, I see. The thing is that df1 ( navigation tarifs) has almost 1million rows, there are all routes that exist today. Of course ther is no company that does all line, so it has 100-150 unique lines over the year. This exercise more Excel-like. You have your route plan (where 150 unique lines, subdivided by AC, month, etc). Now u have to go over your route plan (df2) and grab from df1(navi tarifs) sums according to origination ,destionation, ac,month.

Comment: So we look at the first row in df2, f.e it has orig - A, dest-B, AC-777,Month-1. then it takes this parametrs, filter df1(navi tarifs) according to the inputs, then it sums rur eur usd in separate columns.

Comment: @Tabue can you change your example and example output so I only get the correct output if I do the right thing?

Comment: moment, will see